# How to set a variable in bat/cmd?

Tags: windows, batch-file, input, cmd

i write the bat file which works with some services, and i try to realize menu in it with input parameter, but it can't to read this parameter. There is code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET SvcName=QTCE
SC QUERYEX "%SvcName%" | FIND "STATE" | FIND /v "RUNNING" > NUL && (
    ECHO %SvcName% is not running 
    ECHO.
    ECHO Don't worry ! We start it now! 
    net start QSERVER
    net start QTCE
    ECHO.
    ECHO "%SvcName%" is started
) || (

ECHO "%SvcName%" is running 
ECHO.
ECHO What do you whant i do ? 
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - RESTART QTCE
ECHO 2 - STOP QTCE
ECHO.
SET /p var="Type 1, 2 then press ENTER: "
ECHO ENTERED "%var%"

ECHO Done! Yo're welcome ..    
)
pause
```

But when i start it there is nothing:

[image: result fo running]
What i do wrong ?

Comment: Working Fine For Me. [Look HERE] (https://ibb.co/eRfvDz)

Comment: The variable is being `Set` inside a parenthesised code block, you probably need to enable delayed expansion. A quick alternative fix would be to use `CALL ECHO ENTERED "%%var%%"`

Comment: Or they made a test script that only had the bit inside of the parentheses and didn't include the entire script.

Comment: @aschipfl  Copy Pasted and it worked in first attempt bro

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi, I'm quite sure you ran the batch file more than once, and since there is no `setlocal`, you are getting displayed the old value of the variable; try to enter a different value for every run and you'll see; with the code at hand, [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is needed...

Comment: @aschipfl   Yep You are right Buddy i checked as you said and YOU ARE RIGHT :) Sorry FOR MY FIRST RESPONSE

Comment: `CALL ECHO ENTERED "%%var%%"` Worked for me @aschipfl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your variable `%var%` is not showing is because it is being `SET` inside a parenthesised code block. The usual way to prevent such an occurrence is to enable delayed expansion, and replace the `%` characters with `!`'s.

There's a simpler workaround, in single cases such as this, which is to invoke a `CALL` command:

```bat
CALL ECHO ENTERED "%%var%%"
```

---

I have decided to post this answer as an update to my comment because:

1. `SC QUERYX "%SvcName%"` should be `SC QUERY "%SvcName%"`.
2. You can use a single `FIND` or even `FINDSTR`
3. There's no need to use `NET` when you're already using `SC`.

Using `FIND`:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "SvcName=QTCE"
SC QUERY | FIND /I "%SvcName%" > NUL && (
    ECHO %SvcName% is running
    ECHO=
    ECHO What do you want to do?
    ECHO=
    ECHO 1 - RESTART QTCE
    ECHO 2 - STOP QTCE
    ECHO=
    SET /P "var=Type 1, 2 then press ENTER: "
    CALL ECHO ENTERED "%%var%%"
    ECHO Done! You're welcome ..
) || (
    ECHO %SvcName% is not running
    ECHO=
    ECHO Don't worry! We'll start it now!
    IF /I "%SvcName%"=="QTCE" SC START QSERVER
    SC START %SvcName%
    ECHO=
    ECHO "%SvcName%" is started
)
PAUSE
```

To use `FINDSTR` instead replace line `3` above with:

```bat
SC QUERY "%SvcName%" | FINDSTR /RC:"STATE.*: 4" >NUL && (
```

---

**Note**
The above does not fix the other issues with your code, starting services which you haven't checked the status of and informing the end user a service has been started without checking that it has. Also depending upon how you expand the code, you can only restart a service which is paused, and not pending a continue.

---

**EDIT**
As a courtesy, to your comment and my response, here's a basic restructuring of your script, which prevents the need to use delayed expansion, by not `SET`ting and using `%var%` within a parenthesised code block.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "SvcName=QTCE"

SC QUERY | FIND /I "%SvcName%" > NUL || GOTO SVCSTART

ECHO %SvcName% is running
ECHO=
ECHO What do you want to do?
ECHO=
ECHO 1 - RESTART %SvcName%
ECHO 2 - STOP %SvcName%
ECHO=
SET /P "var=Type 1, 2 then press ENTER: "
ECHO ENTERED "%var%"
ECHO Done! You're welcome ..
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF

:SVCSTART
ECHO %SvcName% is not running
ECHO=
ECHO Don't worry! We'll start it now!
IF /I "%SvcName%"=="QTCE" SC START QSERVER
SC START %SvcName%
ECHO=
ECHO "%SvcName%" is started
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. i've used it now, but one more question ..How it call ' if  ' for input variable ? ''''    ECHO=
    SET /P "var=Type 1, 2 then press ENTER: "
rem ECHO ENTERED "%var%"
rem CALL ECHO ENTERED "%%var%%"
if /I "%var%" == "1" CALL ECHO ENTERED "%var%"     ''''

Comment: Enable delayed expansion! or better still restructure your script to prevent setting and using veriables within the same code block, _(perhaps you could consider using labelled sections with GOTO's and/or CALL's)_.

Comment: hmmm.. how i can to enable delayed expansion ? don't understand..Could u please write some example

Comment: @EugeneTrofimov, please search the site for examples of delayed expansion, _(it is the number one most common issue under the batch file tag)_. I have as a courtesy added an **EDIT** to my answer above to show a basic restructuring of your code. I would also suggest that you dispense with the use of `SET /P` for known inputs in favor of `CHOICE`, where you could use `CHOICE /C 12 /M "Choose an option"` and use its `ERRORLEVEL`.

Answer (score 0):

That's it!

```
CALL ECHO ENTERED "%%var%%"
```

Thanks for all